# how to send email where "from" having 'firstname'<space>'lastname'<email_id> in php

Tags: php, email

i have to send email where email "from" having 'firstname''lastname'.
For ex: first_name="john"
        last_name="Dime"
        email_id="john@john.com"

then from should be like this in the sent mail: From: john dime.

Please help me if u find any solution.

Comment: Please add more details and context, and any code you may already have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is taken from php.net website:

```
<?php
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

You can specify the from field in the additional headers.
You just need to change the webmaster@example.com with the desired string
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php - this can be useful for you

Answer (score 3):

As per [RFC 2822](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2822.html), you simply need to set a header of the form...

```
From: John Dime <john@john.com>
```

...in the headers portion of your email.

Answer (score 1):

I have found instances of mail not being delivered correctly if the from address is not specified using the -f option with sendmail:

```
<?php mail($email, $subject, $body, $headers, "-f $email") ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes simply write your name in "FROM" portion like given below

```
$headers = 'From: Fname Lname<webmaster@example.com>' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
```